# G-Wan perl header for gif file types

Tags: http-headers, g-wan

I've created a perl script c.pl

```
print "Content-type: image/gif\n\n";
...    
and
...
exit 200;
```

output is :

Content-type: image/gif GIF89an

... this is wrong. it seems to generate output of Content-type: text/html prior...

how can I make it output as image/gif header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `Content-type` HTTTP header is `text/html`. But you can (and here should) change it - either by using CGI variables or by writting your HTTP headers from your script.

G-WAN comes with many examples doing that, see [fractal.c](http://gwan.ch/source/fractal.c).

Comment: seems very complicated just for perl script. is it possible to just remove the prior Content-type of text/html? I can just do print "Content-type: image/gif\n\n";

Comment: *"can't Ijust do print "Content-type: image/gif\n\n""?* You should write correct (complete) HTTP headers. Check the HTTP protocol.